# Reproduce Stata code in R, binomial GLM

Tags: r, stata, glm

I'm not a Stata user so I'm trying to reproduce Stata results that are given to me in R. I would like to use a GLM with a complementary log-log function. The stata code I have is:

> glm c IndA fia, family(binomial **s**) link(cloglog) offset(offset)

The R code is:

```
glmt <- glm(data=dataset, c ~ IndA + fia, offset = offset, 
            family = binomial(link = cloglog))
```

Which yields different results from the Stata output. I think the difference is in the variable **s** that is included in the binomial family in Stata (bold in the code). How can I incorporate this variable in the R code?

My dataset looks like:

IndA    s   c   itot    fia       offset

1   23  0   61  0.442622951 -0.494296322
1   25  0   58  0.431034483 -0.544727175
1   27  0   59  0.389830508 -0.527632742
1   31  3   51  0.37254902  -0.673344553
1   28  2   53  0.41509434  -0.634878272
1   26  0   55  0.436363636 -0.597837001

...

where IndA is a dummy variable that is 0 later in the dataset. c is the difference in s (n - (n+1)).

The R output looks like this:

```
    Call:
        glm(formula = c ~ IndA + fia, family = binomial(link = cloglog), 
        data = dataset, offset = offset)

    Deviance Residuals: 
        Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
     -1.2697  -0.9707  -0.8304   1.3688   1.6390  

     Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
     (Intercept)   1.9633     1.9185   1.023    0.306
     IndA         -0.3174     0.3357  -0.945    0.344
     fia          -5.1155     4.8163  -1.062    0.288

    (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 136.81  on 101  degrees of freedom
    Residual deviance: 134.71  on  99  degrees of freedom
    AIC: 140.71

    Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

The Stata output is a little messed up but looks like this:

```
    . glm c IndA fia, family(binomial s ) link(cloglog) offset(offset)

    Iteration 0: log likelihood = -144.17967
    Iteration 1: log likelihood = -133.66053
    Iteration 2: log likelihood = -133.58996
    Iteration 3: log likelihood = -133.58992
    Iteration 4: log likelihood = -133.58992

    Generalized linear models No. of obs = 102
    Optimization : ML Residual df = 99
    Scale parameter = 1
    Deviance = 179.1806126 (1/df) Deviance = 1.809905
    Pearson = 203.965157 (1/df) Pearson = 2.060254
    Variance function: V(u) = u*(1-u/s) [Binomial]
    Link function : g(u) = ln(-ln(1-u/s)) [Complementary log-log]
    AIC = 2.678234
    Log likelihood = -133.5899239 BIC = -278.6917
    OIM

    c Coef. Std. Err. z P>|z| [95% Conf. Interval]
    IndA -.7284992 .2308676 -3.16 0.002 -1.180991 -.2760071
    fia -7.147842 3.185532 -2.24 0.025 -13.39137 -.9043128
    _cons .4404201 1.265651 0.35 0.728 -2.040211 2.921051
    offset (offset)
```

This output is for the whole dataset:

```
IndA    s   c   itot    fia offset  
1   23  0   61  0.442622951 -0.494296322    
1   25  0   58  0.431034483 -0.544727175    
1   27  0   59  0.389830508 -0.527632742    
1   31  3   51  0.37254902  -0.673344553    
1   28  2   53  0.41509434  -0.634878272    
1   26  0   55  0.436363636 -0.597837001    
1   26  0   52  0.461538462 -0.653926467    
1   27  0   53  0.433962264 -0.634878272    
1   29  1   50  0.42    -0.693147181    
1   28  0   52  0.423076923 -0.653926467    
1   28  0   56  0.392857143 -0.579818495    
1   30  4   50  0.4 -0.693147181    
1   26  0   57  0.421052632 -0.562118918    
1   26  1   56  0.428571429 -0.579818495    
1   25  0   58  0.431034483 -0.544727175    
1   26  0   56  0.428571429 -0.579818495    
1   29  3   54  0.388888889 -0.616186139    
1   26  3   58  0.413793103 -0.544727175    
1   23  0   62  0.435483871 -0.478035801    
1   23  0   62  0.435483871 -0.478035801    
1   25  0   59  0.423728814 -0.527632742    
1   27  3   54  0.425925926 -0.616186139    
1   24  0   60  0.433333333 -0.510825624    
1   25  0   60  0.416666667 -0.510825624    
1   25  0   60  0.416666667 -0.510825624    
1   26  0   57  0.421052632 -0.562118918    
1   27  0   55  0.418181818 -0.597837001    
1   27  0   53  0.433962264 -0.634878272    
1   27  0   55  0.418181818 -0.597837001    
1   29  0   56  0.375   -0.579818495    
1   31  0   53  0.358490566 -0.634878272    
1   31  0   52  0.365384615 -0.653926467    
1   34  0   50  0.32    -0.693147181    
1   34  1   51  0.31372549  -0.673344553    
1       33  5   55  0.309090909 -0.597837001    
1   28  0   60  0.366666667 -0.510825624    
1   28  1   58  0.379310345 -0.544727175    
1   27  0   58  0.396551724 -0.544727175    
1   28  0   58  0.379310345 -0.544727175    
1   28  1   58  0.379310345 -0.544727175    
1   27  0   59  0.389830508 -0.527632742    
1   27  0   59  0.389830508 -0.527632742    
1   27  0   57  0.403508772 -0.562118918    
1   29  1   53  0.396226415 -0.634878272    
1   28  0   55  0.4 -0.597837001    
1   30  1   54  0.37037037  -0.616186139    
1   29  0   54  0.388888889 -0.616186139    
1   31  1   50  0.38    -0.693147181    
1   30  0   57  0.350877193 -0.562118918    
1   30  4   57  0.350877193 -0.562118918    
1   26  0   61  0.393442623 -0.494296322    
0   16  0   61  0.442622951 -0.494296322    
0   17  3   58  0.431034483 -0.544727175    
0   14  0   59  0.389830508 -0.527632742    
0   18  0   51  0.37254902  -0.673344553    
0   19  0   53  0.41509434  -0.634878272    
0   19  0   55  0.436363636 -0.597837001    
0   22  2   52  0.461538462 -0.653926467    
0   20  0   53  0.433962264 -0.634878272    
0   21  1   50  0.42    -0.693147181    
0   20  4   52  0.423076923 -0.653926467    
0   16  0   56  0.392857143 -0.579818495    
0   20  3   50  0.4 -0.693147181    
0   17  0   57  0.421052632 -0.562118918    
0   18  1   56  0.428571429 -0.579818495    
0   17  0   58  0.431034483 -0.544727175    
0   18  1   56  0.428571429 -0.579818495    
0   17  1   54  0.388888889 -0.616186139    
0   16  1   58  0.413793103 -0.544727175    
0   15  0   62  0.435483871 -0.478035801    
0   15  0   62  0.435483871 -0.478035801    
0   16  0   59  0.423728814 -0.527632742    
0   19  3   54  0.425925926 -0.616186139    
0   16  1   60  0.433333333 -0.510825624    
0   15  0   60  0.416666667 -0.510825624    
0   15  0   60  0.416666667 -0.510825624    
0   17  0   57  0.421052632 -0.562118918    
0   18  0   55  0.418181818 -0.597837001    
0   20  2   53  0.433962264 -0.634878272    
0   18  3   55  0.418181818 -0.597837001    
0   15  0   56  0.375   -0.579818495    
0   16  0   53  0.358490566 -0.634878272    
0   17  1   52  0.365384615 -0.653926467    
0   16  1   50  0.32    -0.693147181    
0   15  3   51  0.31372549  -0.673344553    
0   12  0   55  0.309090909 -0.597837001    
0   12  0   60  0.366666667 -0.510825624    
0   14  0   58  0.379310345 -0.544727175    
0   15  1   58  0.396551724 -0.544727175    
0   14  0   58  0.379310345 -0.544727175    
0   14  0   58  0.379310345 -0.544727175    
0   14  0   59  0.389830508 -0.527632742    
0   14  0   59  0.389830508 -0.527632742    
0   16  0   57  0.403508772 -0.562118918    
0   18  1   53  0.396226415 -0.634878272    
0   17  1   55  0.4 -0.597837001    
0   16  0   54  0.37037037  -0.616186139    
0   17  0   54  0.388888889 -0.616186139    
0   19  6   50  0.38    -0.693147181    
0   13  0   57  0.350877193 -0.562118918    
0   13  0   57  0.350877193 -0.562118918    
0   13  1   61  0.393442623 -0.494296322
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: it would be helpful to provide the data (or an example) and show at least a subset of the R and Stata output

Comment: Please provide output of `stata` just for those 6 rows of sample data provided, so we can try and replicate using `R`

Answer (score 3):

Stata [family name](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?glm#familyname)

> ```
> familyname               Description
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------
> gaussian                 Gaussian (normal)
> igaussian                inverse Gaussian
> binomial[varnameN|#N]    Bernoulli/binomial
> poisson                  Poisson
> nbinomial[#k|ml]         negative binomial
> gamma                    gamma
> ```

Seems like **s** is one of your variables in dataset. It is hard to tell where this variable should go in `R glm` without seeing your data structure.

See this [link](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2011-04/msg01011.html) for stata glm examples.

[stata glm manual](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rglm.pdf)

> The binomial distribution can be speciﬁed as 1) family(binomial), 2)
>   family(binomial #N), or 3) family(binomial varnameN). In case 2, #N is
>   the value of the binomial denominator N, the number of trials.
>   Specifying family(binomial 1) is the same as specifying
>   family(binomial). In case 3, varnameN is the variable containing the
>   binomial denominator, allowing the number of trials to vary across
>   observations.

Comment: so I'm guessing that `cbind(c,s-c)~...` is the way you want to specify this in the R formula.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it still does not give the same results. I add some data to the original message.

Comment: Could you add output of stata glm for the sample data that you have provided(6 rows)?

Comment: Both the R and Stata output are added.

Comment: I added the total dataset. I do not have the program stata myself. Only the output that is given to me. That's why I want to use R.